# Parse Xml node with same name

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I got problem when I try to parse this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Objects>
  <Object type="0x141" id="Amulet of Resurrection">
    <Class>Equipment</Class>
    <Item />
    <ActivateOnEquip stat="20" amount="2">IncrementStat</ActivateOnEquip>
    <ActivateOnEquip stat="21" amount="2">IncrementStat</ActivateOnEquip>
    <ActivateOnEquip stat="22" amount="2">IncrementStat</ActivateOnEquip>
    <ActivateOnEquip stat="26" amount="2">IncrementStat</ActivateOnEquip>
    <ActivateOnEquip stat="27" amount="2">IncrementStat</ActivateOnEquip>
    <ActivateOnEquip stat="28" amount="2">IncrementStat</ActivateOnEquip>
    <ActivateOnEquip stat="0" amount="20">IncrementStat</ActivateOnEquip>
    <ActivateOnEquip stat="3" amount="20">IncrementStat</ActivateOnEquip>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

My program just read the first ActivateOnEquip but I want it to read all.

Here is my program :

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ParseXML
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParseXMLEquip(@"..\..\obj\Debug\Object\Test.xml");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ParseXMLEquip(string fileName)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(fileName);
            XmlNodeList EquipNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//*");
            {
                foreach (XmlNode EquipNode in EquipNodes)
                {
                    XmlNode Stat = EquipNode["ActivateOnEquip"];

                    if (Stat != null)
                    {
                        switch (Stat.Attributes["stat"].InnerText)
                        {
                            case "0":
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Hp: " + Stat.Attributes["amount"].InnerText);
                            }
                                break;
                            case "3":
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Mp: " + Stat.Attributes["amount"].InnerText);
                            }
                                break;
                            case "20":
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Attack: " + Stat.Attributes["amount"].InnerText);
                            }
                                break;
                            case "21":
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Defense: " + Stat.Attributes["amount"].InnerText);
                            }
                                break;
                            case "22":
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Speed: " + Stat.Attributes["amount"].InnerText);
                            }
                                break;
                            case "28":
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Dexterity: " + Stat.Attributes["amount"].InnerText);
                            }
                                break;
                            case "26":
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Vitality: " + Stat.Attributes["amount"].InnerText);
                            }
                                break;
                            case "27":
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Wisdom: " + Stat.Attributes["amount"].InnerText);
                            }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console just write `Attack : 2`
but i want this

```
Attack : 2 
Defense : 2 
Speed : 2 
Vitality : 2 
Wisdom : 2 
Dexterity : 2 
HP : 20
MP : 20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using Linq2Xml

```
Dictionary<string, string> mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"0","Hp"},
    {"3","Mp"},
    {"20","Attack"},
    {"21","Defence"},
    {"22","Speed"},
    {"28","Dexterity"},
    {"26","Vitality"},
    {"27","Wisdom"},
};

var result = XDocument.Load(filename)
             .Descendants("ActivateOnEquip")
             .Select(x => new { stat = x.Attribute("stat").Value, amount = x.Attribute("amount").Value })
             .ToList();

foreach(var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine( mapping[item.stat] + ": " + item.amount);
}
```

Comment: Can i add like element <Class> in this code. I try to made it but got same problem as before ? And thank alot @EZI